# What are requirements for a cookie authenticating an user?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, cookies

At my company we can't use session to keep users logged because the website is splitted between node and PHP backends. We thought of generating the user a token after he logs in and store both this token and its ID in a cookie so he can be authenticated on subsequent requests. But I'm really lost here.

First is this a good way? Can't we just store the token if we can make it unique across our users?

These data looks critical to me, is there a need to encrypt them? Is there a need to sign them too?

Someone mentionned JWT but I'm not sure it's the right tool for the job (the header would be useless eg.)

To sum it up: what would be the most secure way to store data authenticating an user in a cookie (it won't necessarily be sent over ssl)?

Comment: I would like to point out that without SSL any man in the middle can hijack the session. SSL is essential with sessions. Otherwise sessions are completely worthless. Someone could easily listen for the entire content of an admin level request(headers, cookies, content), and steal the identifying information.

Comment: `We thought of generating the user a token after he logs in and store both this token and its ID in a cookie so he can be authenticated on subsequent requests.` That's precisely what session is.

Comment: `These data looks critical to me, is there a need to encrypt them?` the value of an authentication and session token cannot be greater than the most valuable data that the token is protecting. If you think the data/transaction don't need encrypting/securing, then adding high security around the token kinda misses the point. Since you don't describe what this is going to be used for, it's not possible for us here to tell you whether or not you're going to be fine if you're not using TLS.

Answer (score 1):

> Won't necessarily be sent over SSL

There is NO secure way to do this at all if this is the case. Fix that and you have your choice of `client based sessions` or `server side sessions`, but BOTH methods will require that session data is only EVER sent over SSL, otherwise sessions are worthless.

## Server Side Sessions

In a database common to both backends set an entry in a table with a generated unique session ID, session data, and other maintenance fields that would be useful(time of last activity, etc.)

The table should look like the following:

```
id ( text, 40, not null ), data ( jsonb ), lastCom ( timestamp )
```

These sessions are often used because without special server side code a session can be remotely terminated purely by deleting the entry of the session in the database.

## Client Side Sessions

Often used because with proper SSL and backend invalidation logic these are JUST as secure as Server Side Sessions. However they require backend logic to invalidate sessions otherwise the session isn't secure because there is no remote way for an admin to terminate the session. The user owns the cookie, and just because it failed once doesn't mean they can't retry with the EXACT same data. This is because ALL maintenance on the session is done on the user side, so server side validation is also still required, but doesn't mean you need a database. It just means you need to send an updated cookie with each request(changing the maintenance data inside, like a validity time stamp)

Both methods are plenty secure and can be implemented any number of ways( JWT, passport, etc, etc), but it's up to you to choose which method you'd like to do. Just remember, **session data should only EVER be sent over SSL**

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer, if we keep the user logged in a stateless fashion we don't need session right?

Comment: Keeping a user logged in is a state, plain and simple. Otherwise the best you can do is keep someone logged in based on IP address, and NAT makes that completely nonsensical

Comment: Client state session can be invalidated by adding an entry to a revocation list. It does mean that you have to query a database to check for invalidated session which kinda defeat the point of using client side session, but a revocation list is usually smaller than a session database and it's often easier to scale a distributed system using revocation list than one using a session database.